# Java 8 convert Map<K, List<V>> to Map<V, List<K>>

Tags: java, collections, java-8, mapping, java-stream

I need to convert `Map<K, List<V>>` to `Map<V, List<K>>`.
I've been struggling with this issue for some time.

It's obvious how to do conversion `Map<K, V>` to `Map<V, List<K>>`:

```
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
     Map.Entry::getKey, 
     Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue, toList())
)
```

But I can't find solve an initial issue. Is there some easy-to-ready-java-8 way to do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you were close, you would need to `flatMap` those entries to a `Stream` and collect from there. I've used the already present `SimpleEntry`, but you can use a `Pair` of some kind too.

```
initialMap.entrySet()
          .stream()
          .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().map(v -> new SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(), v)))
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
               Entry::getValue,
               Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())
         ));
```

Well, if you don't want to create the extra overhead of those `SimpleEntry` instances, you could do it a bit different:

```
    Map<Integer, List<String>> result = new HashMap<>();

    initialMap.forEach((key, values) -> {
        values.forEach(value -> result.computeIfAbsent(value, x -> new ArrayList<>()).add(key));
    });
```

Comment: I was just writing an answer (trying it on my IDE first), but it didn't pass compilation. Then you posted an answer that looked exactly like mine, but yours did pass compilation. I couldn't spot the difference, until I compared them in a compare tool and found out I invented a new class - `SimplyEntry`... +1

Comment: @Eran I'll be honest, I did not compile the first version at all... :) the second variant is something I like more, actually

Comment: @Eugene In sake of readability, I'll go for the second solution :)

Comment: Nice! This is one of the exercises in the "challenges" section of the Lambda Hands-on Lab that I (and some colleagues) have given at several conferences over the past few years. Our stream-based solutions are essentially the same, except that the exercise uses `Map<K, Set<V>>`. (And also indentation.) :-) https://github.com/stuart-marks/LambdaHOLv2